# Application with two forms is not showing

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am creating a form application using Visual Studio Express VB 2008 and SQL server 2008. I have two forms. When the program start is not showing me any form. What is to be done that I could use two forms as one program. For example, in one form I want to insert data type state, city .. and the other to use the same information for something else. But like I said, my first step is to see both forms in one program. What should I do to make it work

```
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
' This is my main form called form1 and through it I want to call a form called Country. Belonging to the same project. How to call a form ,,country,, that I could use
Public Class Form1              

    Dim objDS As New DataSet
    Dim objDA As New SqlDataAdapter


    Public Sqlcon As New SqlConnection With {.connectionString = "server=XXX\MSSQL2008;database=TEST;Trusted_Connection=True;"}



    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        If hasConnection() = True Then
            MessageBox.Show("uspijesno povezano sa bazom")

        End If

        getSelc()


    End Sub
    Public Function hasConnection() As Boolean

        Try
            Sqlcon.Open()
            Sqlcon.Close()
            Return True

        Catch ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show("Niste povezani sa bazom")
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Function selc()

        Dim objDS = New DataSet
        Dim objDA As New SqlDataAdapter

        Sqlcon.Close()
        Sqlcon.Open()

        Dim exCommand As String = ""

        Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand


        Dim commitTransaction = Sqlcon.BeginTransaction
        Try


            myCommand = New SqlCommand("EXECUTE " & "regionSelect" & " '" & txtID.EditValue & "', '" & txtShortN.EditValue & "', N'" & txtRegion.EditValue & "', '" & txtStatus.EditValue & "'", Sqlcon)

            myCommand.Transaction = commitTransaction
            objDA.SelectCommand = myCommand
            objDA.Fill(objDS)

            commitTransaction.Commit()
            Sqlcon.Close()

            MessageBox.Show("Podaci su uspijesno poslati")

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            commitTransaction.Rollback()


        End Try


    End Function

    Private Sub SimpleButton3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnInsert.Click
        'insert()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnConfirm_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnConfirm.Click
        getSelc()
    End Sub

    Public Function getSelc()
        objDS = New DataSet
        Dim com As New SqlCommand

        Sqlcon.Close()
        Sqlcon.Open()
        GridControl1.DataSource = Nothing
        Try

            com = New SqlCommand("EXECUTE rS '" & txtID.Text & " ' , ' " & txtRegion.Text & "' , '" & txtShortN.Text & "', ' " & txtStatus.Text & " ' ", Sqlcon)

            'com = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblRegion", Sqlcon)

            objDA.SelectCommand = com
            objDA.Fill(objDS)
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            GridControl1.DataSource = objDS.Tables(0)


            objDA.Dispose()
            com.Dispose()

            Sqlcon.Close()
            MessageBox.Show("Im here")

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

        'GridControl1.DataSource = Nothing

        'objDS.Tables(0).Rows.Clear()
    End Function

    Private Sub SimpleButton4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SimpleButton4.Click

        getSelc()

        Dim newRow As DataRow
        newRow = objDS.Tables(0).NewRow
        newRow.Item(0) = txtID.EditValue
        newRow.Item(1) = txtShortN.EditValue
        newRow.Item(2) = txtRegion.EditValue
        newRow.Item(3) = txtStatus.EditValue


        objDS.Tables(0).Rows.Add(newRow)
    End Sub

    Private Sub SimpleButton3_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SimpleButton3.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub SimpleButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SimpleButton1.Click
        Country.Show()    ' => Is this a good way, and is there any better way and more efficient
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Start by showing what you tried. What are the forms called? Show us some code, like the bits where you call `Form.Show`. Most of all, please look around the site and do some research into your problem and into how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot load more than one form on Application Startup. You have to load any one form first then show others from its `Form_Load` event.

```
Private Sub StartupForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
   Dim form2 As New Form2
   form2.Show()
   Dim form3 As New Form3
   form3.Show()
End Sub
```

Or you can load forms manually on Button Click.
Set the `Form1` as a `StartupForm` from the **Project Property Window**.

Now, Add a button in your first form `button1` and write down some code to display another form.

```
Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
   Dim form2 As New Form2
   form2.Show()
End Sub
```

Another one is calling main method. For that you need to assign Main method in your **Project Property Window**

```
Module mainModule
    Sub Main()
       Dim form2 As New Form2
       form2.Show()
       Dim form3 As New Form3
       form3.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there another way. I need to know other ways that I could choose the best.

Comment: Another approach is `Main` method. But, I wont suggest you to use that method. It could be difficult to handle application termination. Read more about `Main` method on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235406.aspx)

Comment: Ok. Thank you. 
I appreciate the effort